# PCA9685 - Hardware problem with diode?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, servo

I'm working on a project, where I need to run several high-torque servos. For that I bought come of these [PCA9685](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B093LB85QK/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apanp_DWVjpjgucRLvc) boards.

I hooked everything up with my arduino and connected an external 5V - max 3A power supply for driving the servos. After some succesful tests, the board seems to be broken as no servo move anymore.
With my multimeter I looked for the broken component and found the following - in front of the transistor is, in my opinion, a ten diode with label Y4 installed - At the input (right) are still 5 V, but no longer at the output and accordingly not at the V+ pins of the servo connectors.

[image]

According to the internet, a ten diode has a maximum of 300mW, which for 5V results in 60mA, which of course is less then my servos require.

Do you agree with me? Could this be the problem?
If so, do you know the "correct" PCA board that is able to power high torque servos?

Comment: Yes, I concur with your diagnosis. You can use that board fine, just don't provide the 5V to the servos from it - connect them direct to the power supply.

Comment: Newer versions of the board (based on the Adafruit design https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-16-Channel-PWM-Servo-Driver-PCB) replace that section with a AOD417 Mosfet. See the "reverse voltage protection" section of the schematic at the same link location. I've not had any trouble running hobby servos  from the revision C board.